# Saving a picture at a certain storage location and storing its path into a SQLite Database Table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, java-io, android-image

I'm working on an app with SQLite and I want to be able to select a profile picture for an user (that will be saved locally). Basically I have a crop activity and I want to select a picture, crop it and compress it, then I want to save it in the phone at a certain storage path that will not be deleted by cleaning the cache and will also not be visible in the Gallery of the phone (important). In the mean time, I want the new path to be saved in my SQLite database so it can be used to rapidly load the image in an ImageView where it's necessary.

This is the code where I load, crop, compress and also preview the picture in a test ImageView.

```
public void chooseProfilePicture(){
        CropImage.activity().setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).setAspectRatio(1,1).start(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                assert result != null;
                profileImageURI = result.getUri();
                File thumbnailURI = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(profileImageURI.getPath()));
                try
                {
                    compressedImageFile = new Compressor(activity_user_data.this)
                            .setMaxHeight(400)
                            .setMaxWidth(400)
                            .setQuality(90)
                            .compressToBitmap(thumbnailURI);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                compressedImageFile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);
                profilePicker.setImageBitmap(compressedImageFile);
                isImageSelected = true;
            }
            else
                if(resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE)
                {
                    assert result != null;
                    Exception error = result.getError();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: My question is how to store the picture at a custom location that is not visible in the gallery?

Comment: save file in a directory (name followed by a dot) example  .myDir or .myDir1

Comment: see two ways here: https://www.maketecheasier.com/prevent-folder-included-gallery-android/